# Is a CSS reset still necessary?

Tags: css

Are CSS reset pages ([like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset)) still necessary in today's age? I assume the answer is yes but looking to see if I get surprised.

I've read thoroughly the [HTML5 BoilerPlate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) from Paul Irish but don't see myself adopting a standard that isn't necessarily standard. [Rhetorical] Isn't this at least some cause of what got us into this mess if you put aside the IE bashing?

Comment: Basically the same as [
Is it OK to use a CSS reset stylesheet?
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/167531/is-it-ok-to-use-a-css-reset-stylesheet), except your question is more loaded.

Comment: Yes - but as you will notice that question is right at 2 years old. Where I could infer that the same situation still exists 2 years is quite a bit of time for answers to shift and change. This isn't a question to which the answer will always stay the same.

Comment: The last activity was 7 years, 3 months ago...
Is this question still relevant in 2019?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

yes, the same reasons they were created still exist: several browsers have several different implementations of CSS, and this is one way to take care of them.

Answer (score 6):

Necessary? No.

Some developers like to use them, some don't, but they are definitely not *necessary*.

Answer (score 2):

Necessary? No. I actually think it never has been necessary. But a CSS reset will help you to make your project look the same in every browser and might save you a lot of time of browser-testing and debugging.

I'm using my own reset file, customized to my needs:
http://www.htmltweaks.com/Reset_Browser-Specific_CSS_Styles

Answer (score 1):

only if you want to have an easier time getting your site to look the same in all browsers.

If that is not a requirement, or if you don't mind having a hard time getting IE to follow suit then by all means. A lot of developers every day are making sites without css-resets.

Answer (score 0):

They are no less necessary than they ever were.  IE6 still has a significant market share.