# can anyone explain why we use * in css?

Tags: css

Can anyone please explain about this ?

```
 display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
```

Why we use * before that display ?

Reference: http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/EDp8R/

Comment: That's a IE specific hack. I don't remember for which version though.

Comment: You can see the answer in the below link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8715860/what-does-mean-in-css

Comment: @Vikram: No, this is different. That `*` is a selector and this isn't.

Comment: Yes @Vikram. Thats a different star. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*property: value

Although Internet Explorer 7 corrected its behavior when a property name is prefixed with an underscore or a hyphen, other non-alphanumeric character prefixes are treated as they were in IE6. Therefore, if you add a non-alphanumeric character such as an asterisk (*) immediately before a property name, the property will be applied in IE and not in other browsers. Unlike with the hyphen and underscore method, the CSS specification makes no reservations for the asterisk as a prefix, so use of this hack could result in unexpected behavior as the CSS specifications evolve.

*property: value applies the property value in IE 7 and below. It may or may not work in future versions. Warning: this uses invalid CSS.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1690683/3958365

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks3.shtml

Comment: Thanks for the info. It is helpful. :)