# * { margin:0; padding:0; } in 2012

Tags: css, html, browser, cross-browser

What is the current state of differences in browser rendering? This method of "CSS Resetting" is certainly inefficient, is it ever necessary with today's modern browsers?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739154/is-a-css-reset-still-necessary

Comment: I didn't see that post when I posed this question, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a nice way to get the box model to be as standard as possible between browsers. I'm sure each browser has their little "nice" looking default styles that you'll always forget to take into account when dealing with width/height.

What is inefficient about doing a general css reset? It maybe extra CSS, but I don't think you should be worrying about the efficiency of that.

Answer (score 2):

"today's modern browsers" only covers a percentage of the browser market share ([source](http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php)); you still have an amazing percentage of users that have older or non-standard browsers.

Even in modern browsers, there are subtle differences in their default state, making a reset css useful to ensure one starts on equal footing despite user agent differences. This applies to browsers across the board, not just odd-man-out Internet Explorer, but even browsers that are known in the industry for being compliant and at the cutting edge of new standards ([source 1](http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/06/dealing-with-browser-differences-in-css-3/), [source 2](http://blog.orite.com.au/web_development/2009-04-09/css-implementation-chart-ie6-ie7-ie8/), [source 3](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/blog/about/five_css_design_browser_differences_i_can_live_with/))

That said... no one is resetting with `*`, because that is inefficient and far too broad. Most people favor something targeted and specific, one designed to deal with known disparities in "modern browsers": http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/